# Photo/image (not document) scanning for low-end USB scanners

Tags: windows, scanning, photoshop

I run Windows 10 x64 and have an Adobe Creative Cloud subscription - and a (low-end) Canoscan LiDE 210 USB scanner.

Canon does make 64-bit TWAIN drivers available for this scanner on Windows, but Adobe Photoshop does not support TWAIN anymore (IIRC, Photoshop CS4 32-bit is the last version to support TWAIN).

There is no standalone scanning program included in Canon's driver package.

Canon's driver also includes a very basic WIA driver that does not expose any custom UI for altering scanning parameters. Attempting to perform a WIA scan (from within Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Photoshop, or Windows Fax and Scan) only shows a very simplistic Windows-provided UI.

I thought the underlying WIA interface still exposes a number of tweakable parameters - is there any other program out there that would let me scan how I want to?

Answer (score 1):

I've used in the past the vuescan driver for an older scanner on a newer printer for which there was no native driver available.

[Vuescan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_lide_210.html#technical-information) offers free downloads for your specific scanner (linked here) and appears to have a reasonably comprehensive interface. The text of the link indicates that it will work when installed with a native driver. The text also indicates that it will install its own driver if a native driver is not included.

I cannot address specifically the WIA or Twain portion of your question. A free download of a proven product is a good start, however.